# I think I have discovered a new sorting algorithm using binary search tree.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees, sorting

If we some how transform a Binary Search Tree into a form where no node other than root may have both right and left child and the nodes the right sub-tree of the root may only have right child, and vice versa, such a configuration of BST is inherently sorted with its root being approximately in the middle (in case of nearly complete BST’s). To to this we need to do reverse rotations. Unlike AVL and red black trees, where roatations are done to make the tree balanced, we would do reversed rotations.

I would like to explain the pseudo code and logical implementation of the algorithm through the following images. The algorithm is to first sort the left subtree with respect to the root and then the right subtree. These two subparts will be opposite to each other, that is, left would interchange with right. For simplicity I have taken a BST with right subtree, with respect to root, sorted.

To improve the complexity as compared to tree sort we can augment the algorithm shown in the photos below. We can add a flag to each node where 0 stands for a normal node while 1 is when the node has non null right child, in the original unsorted BST. The nodes with flag 1 have an entry in a hash table with key being their pointers and the values being the right most node. For example node 23's pointer would map to 30.5's pointer. Then we would not have to traverse all the nodes in between for the iteration. If we have 23's pointer and 30.5's pointer we can do the required operation in O(1). This will bring down time complexity of the algorithm, as compared to tree sort in practical circumstances, although not asymtotically. This is because the time complexity =O(n(logn))(dues to formation of BST)+O(n)(inorder traversal in tree sort). Our augmented algorithm reduces this O(n) only.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So do you have a question? I must tell you that I am not clicking on a link from a new user nor do I recommend anyone else do so either.

Comment: I think this belongs on https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for reposting this, with the images shown!

Comment: With that said I'm not seeing what new ground is broken here, especially since sorting algorithms have been so thoroughly covered. This appears to be but another rehash of divide-and-conquer-and-merge: Two lists of size $n_1,n_2$, each sorted, can be merged into each other to make a new sorted list in linear time [$O(\min\{n_1,n_2\})$, if one list is much bigger than the other and you are careful].

Comment: *I should have said instead $O(\min\{n_1,n_2 \log(n_1)\})$ if $n_1$ is much larger than $n_2$. For all I know though perhaps this can be improved slightly, maybe to say $\min\{n_1,n_2 \log(n_1/n_2)\})$.

Comment: What if I had a flag to each node where 0 stands for a normal node while 1 is when the node has non null right child, in the original unsorted BST. The nodes with flag 1 have an entry in a hash table with key being their pointers and the values being the right most node. For example node 23's pointer would map to 30.5's pointer. Then I would not have to traverse all the nodes in between for the iteration. This will bring down time complexity less than linear assuming we receive Original BST as input. Isn't it an improvement from tree sort's linear time complexity? –

Comment: @UdayUppal I'm not sure what you mean, as sorting $n$ numbers in general has a lower-bound of $\Omega(n \log n)$ comparisons. If we assume those $n$ numbers are say, integers within a certain range, then it is possible to do better than $n \log n$ but in general $n \log n$ comparisons is the best we can hope for.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That's why I wrote "assuming we receive BST as input". That O(n(logn))  is the cost of formation of BST in the first place. If we include the cost to create the BST then Time complexity =O(n(logn))(dues to formation of BST)+O(n)(inorder traversal in tree sort). I want to reduce this n. Though it won't impact asymptotically, it might be better off in practical circumstances.